# Why aren't I able to simply write out an elgg variable to a file?

Tags: php, file-io, elgg

Within an existing php file in an elgg plugin page I have no problem running the basic function:

```
file_put_contents('test.txt', "MyName");
```

and within test.txt I see MyName.  But if I try to write out a variable of a simple name string like:

```
file_put_contents('test.txt', $page_owner->name);
```

the file test.txt is empty, even though I know that the variable $page_owner->name isn't empty because I see the text when I elgg_echo().  What do I need to do to write out something like $page_owner->name from elgg?

Comment: What happens when you do 

    file_put_contents('test.txt', print_r($page_owner, true));

Comment: I suspect `$page_owner->name` isn't a string. You can use `var_dump()` to check.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses!  Unfortunately file_put_contents('test.txt', print_r($page_owner, true)); also results in an empty test.txt as well.

Comment: As for var_dump(), I see the following within the dump: ["name"]=> string(16).  Does that confirm that $page_owner->name is a string after all?